# Find $O(f)$ for a given function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics

Task:

Find $O(f)$ for the following functions $f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb R $ .

a) $f(n)=2f(n/2) + n^3$

e) $ f(n)=2f(\sqrt n)  + log_2(n) $

I don't understand the meaning of $f(n/2)$ or $f(\sqrt n)$ since $f$ is defined on the natural numbers. Also confusingly $f$ is on the LFS and on the RHS of the equality. I could imagine that I should find all functions $f$ that satisfy the equality at first but it looks very difficult for e). Although WolframAlpha found those functions.

Comment: In which context you are studying this? Computer science or analysis?

Comment: I think you should think $f:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ and then assume $f$ is smooth (at least continuous) and then apply the recursive relation.

Comment: Computer science. It's a course you can study in your first semester.

Comment: Hint: Use the master's Theorem (which you quite likely encountered in the course), at least for part a). $f(n/2)$ and $f(\sqrt n)$ is sloppiness from computer scientists, here is a rigorous statement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method (of course there are also many sloppy Wikipedia articles, but many are very good and that is a different subject).

Comment: Also we are using the programming language GAP.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch They can also write $f(2n) = 2f(n) + 8n^3$ and the statement now is always correct. Similarly, $f(n^2) = 2f(n) + 2\log_2(n).$ Of course, this skips some terms, so we can assume some bound of the form $f(2n + k) \asymp f(2n)$ for $1 \leq k \leq 2n$ (the implicit constants universal).

Comment: I still do not know how to do e). Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for a)

Using the master's theorem we get $O(f) \in O(n^3) $ because $2<2^3$ (first $2$ is from $2f $, second $2$ is from $n/2$ and the $3$ from $n^3$).